# Angular 2 observable subscription not triggering

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an issue with a subscription to an observable not triggering.

I have a layout using the side nav layout directive looking like this:

```
<md-sidenav-layout class="nav-bar">


    <md-sidenav #start>
        <nav>
            <a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
        </nav> 
        <button md-button (click)="start.close()">Close</button>
    </md-sidenav>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</md-sidenav-layout>
```

What I need to do is open the side nav from the component that the router-outlet is displaying.

One such component might look like this:

```
@Component({

    providers: [SidenavService, MdIconRegistry],
    directives: [MdIcon],
    templateUrl: `<md-icon (click)="toggleSidenav()">menu</md-icon>`,
    styleUrls: ["./home.component.scss"]
})

export class Home {

    myColor: string;

    constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService) {
        this.myColor = "primary";

        this.sidenavService.getSidenavObs().subscribe(state => {console.log("state change")});
    }


    toggleSidenav() {

        this.sidenavService.toggleSidenav("open");
    }

}
```

I have created a service that returns an observable like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class SidenavService {

    private toggle = new Subject<string>();
    private toggleObs = this.toggle.asObservable();

    getSidenavObs() {
        return this.toggleObs;
    }

    toggleSidenav(state: string) {
        this.toggle.next(state);
    }

}
```

Finally the code for the parent class (that belongs with the side nav layout HTML):

```
@Component({
  providers: [MdSidenav, SidenavService],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, MD_SIDENAV_DIRECTIVES, MD_BUTTON_DIRECTIVES],
  selector: "app",
  templateUrl: "app.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.scss"],
})

export class App {

  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService, private sidenav: MdSidenav) {
    this.subscription = sidenavService.getSidenavObs().subscribe( status => {
      console.log("state change");
      sidenav.open();
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    }, () => {
      console.log("completed");
    });
  }
}
```

Now my problem is that the subscription in the App component does not trigger, however, the subscription in the Home component (which is what the router-outlet displays) is triggered as expected.

Am I missing something here?

I followed this guide: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The same service instance isn't being shared across your App and Home components because you have listed `SidenavService` as a provider for both.

When you define service provider in the `providers` entry of a Component decorator, that service is then available to that component and all of its children as a singleton, meaning the same instance of the service will be used.

If you redefine a provider in a child component, it will create a *new* instance of the service and will no longer share the same service instance as its parent/ancestor.

If you are using `SidenavService` in both App and Home components and need the same instance, you should only provide it in the App component and remove it from the `providers` entry of Home.

For more information on DI, have a read of the following links:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html

Comment: Thanks Michael!!.You saved me

Comment: great, that helped me a lot !

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this saved me a lot of time !

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that contrary to other frameworks Angular doesn't seem to force `Service`s to be *singletons* by default.

Thus what you encounter is a situation when you declared each `Component` of yours to have its own instance of the `Service`. This results in each instance having different attributes (`toggle` and `toggleObs`). Schematically:

App -> SidenavService [**instance A**]

Home -> SidenavService [**instance B**]

You need to change your declarations to match *Singleton Services* as described in [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services). Which results in sharing only a single instance of a `Service` among all `Components`. Schematically:

App -> SidenavService [**instance A**]

Home -> SidenavService [**instance A**]