# Angular 5 Rxjs Subject.subscribe() not triggering in multiple components

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm using rxjs and subjects to update my two of components.

I'm subscribing to a subject in a service, but when the .next method is called on the Subject, it only updates one of my components.

The application consist of a WebsocketService to initialize a websocketconnection, a NotificationService that uses the WebsocketService to connect to the backend and send/recieve notifications.

I have a NotificationComponent where I can create a new notification. In this component I subscribed to the Subject in the NotificationService, and display the notification when it gets updated. This works just fine, the message reaches the backend, and get's updated in all browsers that currently have a connection.

The next step for me was to show this notification in the HeaderComponent. I injected the NotificationService here and subscribed to the same Subject, however when I send the notification, the HeaderComponents subscription does not fire. The console.log message never shows up in the console.

**WebSocketService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject, Subject, Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class WebsocketService {

  constructor() { }

  private subject: ReplaySubject<MessageEvent>;

  public connect(url): ReplaySubject<MessageEvent> {
    if (!this.subject) {
      this.subject = this.create(url);
      console.log("Successfully connected: " + url);
    }
    return this.subject;
  }

  private create(url): ReplaySubject<MessageEvent> {

    //create connection
    let ws = new WebSocket(url);

    //define observable
    let observable = Observable.create(
      (obs: Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
        ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
        ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
        ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
        return ws.close.bind(ws);
      });

    //define observer
    let observer = {
      next: (data: Object) => {
        if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          console.log("---sending ws message---");
          ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
      }
    };

    return ReplaySubject.create(observer, observable);
  }
}
```

**NotificationService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { WebsocketService } from './websocket.service';
import { Notification } from './../model/notification'

const NOTIFICATION_URL = 'ws://localhost:8080/Kwetter/socket'


@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {

  public _notification: ReplaySubject<Notification>;

  constructor(websocketService: WebsocketService) {

    this._notification = <ReplaySubject<Notification>>websocketService
      .connect(NOTIFICATION_URL)
      .map((response: MessageEvent): Notification => {
        let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        return {
          sender: data.author,
          message: data.message
        }
      });
  }

  sendMessage(notification) {
    console.log("---calling .next()---");
    this._notification.next(notification);
  }
}
```

**NotificationComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NotificationService } from '../services/notification.service';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { Notification } from './../model/notification';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-notifications',
  templateUrl: './notifications.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notifications.component.css']
})
export class NotificationsComponent implements OnInit {

  notification: Notification;
  text: string;

  constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService, private userService: UserService) {

    if (this.notification == null) {
      this.notification = new Notification("", "");
    }
    notificationService._notification.subscribe(notification => {
      console.log("---notification has been updated---")
      this.notification = notification;
    });
  }

  sendMsg() {
    let newNot = new Notification(this.userService.getUser(), this.text);
    this.notificationService.sendMessage(newNot);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**HeaderComponent**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';
import { NotificationService } from '../../services/notification.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Profile } from '../../model/profile';
import { User } from '../../model/user';
import { Notification } from '../../model/notification';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private notification: Notification;
  private loggedIn = false;
  private user: User;

  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router, private notificationService: NotificationService) {

    console.log("---constructor headercomponent---");
    console.log(this.notification);

    this.notificationService._notification.subscribe(notification => {
      console.log("---header notification has been updated---");
      this.notification = notification;
    });

    if (this.notification == null) {
      this.notification = new Notification("", "");
    }

    this.subscription = this.userService.profile$.subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
      if (user !== null) {
        this.loggedIn = true;
      }
      else this.loggedIn = false;
    });

    this.loggedIn = userService.isLoggedIn();
    this.user = userService.getUser();
  }

  logout() {
    this.userService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
  }

  home() {
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
  }

  myProfile() {
    console.log("click");
    this.router.navigate(['profile', this.userService.getUser().id]);
  }

  getLoggedIn(): void {
    this.loggedIn = !!this.userService.isLoggedIn();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLoggedIn();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

The NotificationComponent is shown by using the router-outlet, and the header component is always shown by using the selector tags, but I don't think this should matter.

```html
<div>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <div class="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

I found the thread below, that suggested using ReplaySubject in case I subscribe after the event is fired (I don't think is the case, but I tried anyway). This didn't work.

Also, I only have a single app.module where I declare the providers.
Since I'm using the same code for both components, why does .subscribe only work within the NotificationComponent?

[Angular 2: Observable / Subscription not triggering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374331/angular-2-observable-subscription-not-triggering?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[image: Console view]

Comment: _"I only have a single app.module where I declare the providers"_ So you don't have a module for the route?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question.

What I meant to say by that comment in that I pass the services to the providers array in app.module. I only have a single app module.

I don't provide the service again in a specific component within @Component. So my service shouldn't be instantiated twice.

Comment: _"I only have a single app module"_ is not the same as _"I only have one module"_. If e.g. your routes are loaded lazily then you have more than one module.

Comment: In that case I'm importing several modules:
https://github.com/bvkeersop/KwetterFrontend/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts

However I provide the service to the appmodule so if I'm understanding correctly that's the one injected in my components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you see has to do with how RxJS works and how your stream is created. Let's take a look at `WebsocketService`:

```
let observable = Observable.create(
  (obs: Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
    ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
```

`obs` is new for every subscription, but `ws` is always the same. So when you subscribe a second time in the `NotificationComponent` the `onmessage` callback invokes `next` only for that subscription. Hence only that component receives messages.

You can verify that by commenting out `notificationService._notification.subscribe` in the `NotificationComponent`. Then the `HeaderComponent` will receive messages.

One simple solution is to add the `share` operator in the `NotificationService`:

```
this._notification = <ReplaySubject<Notification>>websocketService
  .connect(NOTIFICATION_URL)
  .map((response: MessageEvent): Notification => {
    let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
    return {
      sender: data.author,
      message: data.message
    }
  })
.share();
```

That means that the subscription upstream of `.share()` will be shared, i.e. `(obs: Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
        ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);` will be called only once and both components will receive messages.

Btw.: RxJs offers [support for websockets](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-webSocket). You can create a stream with `Observable.webSocket(url);` and get rid of some code.

Comment: Perfect answer, and nicely explained! Thanks!