# .subscribe to BehaviourSubject<any> not firing in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am trying to subscribe to a service I am writing so I can update an `mat-autocomplete` input when a language dropdown is changed.

the stackoverflow question I found is;

[Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular/35568924#35568924)

However, when I implement this the subscription method is not firing? I have the following;

My app.component.ts;

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslationEmitterService } from '../../services/translation.emitter.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [ TranslationEmitterService ]
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private translationService: TranslationEmitterService) {
        translate.addLangs(["en", "pt", "fr"]);
        translate.setDefaultLang('pt');

        let browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
        translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|pt|fr/) ? browserLang : 'en');
    }


}
```

My Component html;

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Select Language
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="switchLanguage('pt')"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gr"></span> Portugese</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="switchLanguage('en')"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gr"></span> English</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="switchLanguage('fr')"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gr"></span> French</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Observable Service;

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class TranslationEmitterService {
    private _languageChangedSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(0);
    languageChange$ = this._languageChangedSource.asObservable();


    changeLanguage(lang) {
        console.log("in change language " + lang);
        this._languageChangedSource.next(lang);
    }
}
```

my component for switching the language which calls the change;

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { TranslationEmitterService } from '../../../services/translation.emitter.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'nav-menu',
    templateUrl: './navmenu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navmenu.component.css']
})
export class NavMenuComponent {
    public isCollapsed = true;
    public status = false;

    constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private translationEmitterService: TranslationEmitterService) {

    }

    public switchLanguage(language: string) {
        console.log("switching language");
        this.translate.use(language);
        this.translationEmitterService.changeLanguage(language);
    }
}
```

and finally I subscribe to the event in my component;

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.translationSubscription = this.translationService.languageChange$.subscribe(

        // lang => this.refreshAutoCompleteItems(lang)
        x => console.log(x)
    );
}
```

A copy of the component is here [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/dM82pZW3)

No when I trigger the `switchLanguage` method i get the output `switching language` and `in change language fr` output, but the component observing is not triggering?

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Try subscribing to this.translationService._languageChangedSource directly. I don't think asObservable is needed. I have written code without that and it works.

Comment: It is needed if you care about the encapsulation. You might only want to expose the observable stream but keep the emiting logic behind the service method's facade.

Comment: Your code looks fine, does console shows any error?

Comment: @Vikas no there are no erros I can see either, its just the `console.log(x)` is not firing.

Comment: @Vikas also to add when the program runs initially it does fire the subscription as '0' is logged for the value of x?

Comment: @MatthewFlynn your code seems I triggered switchLanguage function inside my component constructor and passed "test" as parameter I got all three console.logs

Comment: @MatthewFlynn check the demo I attached if you are still getting the error.

Comment: how are you invoking the switchLanguage() method?

Comment: can you share your html

Comment: @Vikas yes I have added more detail to my code including the dropdown html and also provided a pastbin link for the component (I have stripped out some of the bumpf in this though so if you cant see anything I can provide the whole component code)

Comment: I think it could be down to this maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033723/angular-2-observable-subscription-not-triggering

Comment: again just to update, I updated the provider so it was injected at the app.comonent.ts level and added this to the question, but it is still not firing?

Comment: @MatthewFlynn register your service in  `(@NgModule.providers)` in app.module.ts

Answer (score 5):

One possible cause of the problem is that each of the two components has its own instance of the service. When one component calls the `changeLanguage` service method, the other component does not receive the notification because it has subscribed to the other service instance.

To make sure that a single instance of the service is shared by the two components, it should be provided only once. This can be accomplished by **providing the service at the module level only** and by removing it from the `providers` list of the components:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        TranslationEmitterService 
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `map` your service call.

```
this._languageChangedSource.next(lang).map(r=>r.json());

this.translationEmitterService.changeLanguage(language).map(r=>r.json());
```

Map is required in service when you are using subscribe in your component.

Also your service has to return an `Observable`. To which your component method can `subscribe`.

Comment: but my service does return an observable? Also adding `map` to the `.next` throws an error `map does not exist on type void` even when I have the relevant import on the service.

Comment: Thats because your service isnt returning anything. It should return Observable.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding what you mean sorry? The service stream is observable and the element I am subscribing to.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Demo below

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviorsubject-simple-program)

```
private _languageChangedSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(0);
```

You have passed 0 as intial value when instantiating the BehaviorSubject. That's why you are getting intial value as 0.

**Note**
When instantiating BehaviorSubject we need to give a default value. It's a must.

```
this.switchLanguage("test");
```

I passed test as the switchLanguage function parameter and I got below logs.

```
switching language
in change language test
test
```

I hope this will resolve your problem. If you have any problem let me know.